# Low WSO2ESB https proxy service performance

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, tomcat7, wso2-esb

I am creating some proxy services to a Web-Services which have the restriction that all connection must be secured (over https).
After doing some configuration changes on the WSO2Server I could finally create sucessfully those proxy services. The connection between the client and the final Web-Service through WSO2Esb it is ok, but the connection is very slow.

To dischard network problems we allow requests over http with a very good performance. To sum up, the same client request over http lasts less than 1 second and if we do it over https lasts 20 seconds more or less.

Other test done to try to understand where is the problem: I did requests over https directly to the end Web Service without passing through WSO2ESB. In this case the https performace is very good to (quite similar as if the request has been done through http).

So the problem could be in some part of the WSO2ESB server configuration. Always the first https request lasts the same (20 seconds), and If I do more than one the following lasts less than 1.5 second. So the problem could be some kind of timeout doing something related to the ssl connection.

More useful information:

- wso2server version: 4.8.1
- Java versions tested: 1.7.0_45 and 1.8.0_60
- Added parameter in CARBON_HOME/bin/wso2server.sh: -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
- Tomcat connector configuration from `CARBON_HOME/repository/conf/tomcat  /catalina-server.xml:`

  ```
  <Connector  protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
  port="8888"
  bindOnInit="false"
  sslProtocol="TLS"
  sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
  maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
  acceptorThreadCount="2"
  maxThreads="250"
  minSpareThreads="50"
  disableUploadTimeout="false"
  enableLookups="false"
  connectionUploadTimeout="120000"
  maxKeepAliveRequests="200"
  acceptCount="200"
  server="WSO2 Carbon Server"
  clientAuth="false"
  compression="on"
  scheme="https"
  secure="true"
  SSLEnabled="true"
  compressionMinSize="2048"
  noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
  compressableMimeType="..."
  URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
  ```

Maybe I missed something in axis2.xml configuration file ($CARBON_HOME/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml)?. Here is the part related to:

- TransportReceiver (https part):

```
 
    <transportReceiver name="https" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLListener">
        <parameter name="port" locked="false">8443</parameter>
        <parameter name="non-blocking" locked="false">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="bind-address" locked="false">XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX</parameter>
        <parameter name="WSDLEPRPrefix" locked="false">https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8443</parameter>
        <parameter name="httpGetProcessor" locked="false">org.wso2.carbon.transport.nhttp.api.PassThroughNHttpGetProcessor
        <parameter name="SSLProtocol">TLSv1.2</parameter>
        <parameter name="keystore" locked="false">
            <KeyStore>
                <Location>repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks</Location>
                <Type>JKS</Type>
                <Password>XXX</Password>
                <KeyPassword>XXX</KeyPassword>
            </KeyStore>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="truststore" locked="false">
            <TrustStore>
                <Location>repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks</Location>
                <Type>JKS</Type>
                <Password>XXX</Password>
            </TrustStore>
        </parameter>
   </transportReceiver>
```

- TransportSender (https part):

```
 
    <transportSender name="https" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLSender">
        <parameter name="non-blocking" locked="false">true
        <parameter name="SSLProtocol">TLSv1.2</parameter>
        <parameter name="keystore" locked="false">
            <KeyStore>
                <Location>repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks</Location>
                <Type>JKS</Type>
                <Password>XXXX</Password>
                <KeyPassword>XXXX</KeyPassword>
            </KeyStore>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="truststore" locked="false">
            <TrustStore>
                <Location>repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks</Location>
                <Type>JKS</Type>
                <Password>XXXXX</Password>
            </TrustStore>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="HostnameVerifier">AllowAll</parameter>        
    </transportSender>
```

---

***PROBLEM SOLVED.***

The low performance SSL problem was caused by a restriction in the network firewall. The firewall was blocking the connections to the DNS server, so WSO2ESB couldn't validate properly the client certificate and the client hostname.

After having added a new rule in the firewall the SSL performance of the WSO2ESB is quite good.

Thank you.

Comment: if your problem is still exist i am happy yo help you. but can please explain what you are going to do in very brief. without explaining what you have done so far just comment what you are going yo achieve.

Comment: Finally I could solve that problem. The problem was caused because the machine couldn't connect to the DNS server due to a firewall restriction.